# Transform hash result of multiple group result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

This is the output of `Product.group([:name, :category]).order([:name, :category]).count`:

```
{
  ["Product A", "Category 2"]=>42,
  ["Product A", "Category 3"]=>83,
  ["Product A", "Category 4"]=>47,
  ["Product B", "Category 2"]=>1,
  ["Product B", "Category 3"]=>4,
  ["Product B", "Category 4"]=>10,
  ["Product C", "Category 3"]=>2,
  ["Product C", "Category 4"]=>4,
  ["Product D", "Category 1"]=>6,
  ["Product D", "Category 2"]=>13,
  ["Product D", "Category 3"]=>57,
  ["Product D", "Category 4"]=>27
}
```

Each product can be of categories 1-4. I need to have the count of the 0's as well for the final transformation.

Desired transformation array columns: Product Name, Count of Category 1, Count of Category 2, Count of Category 3 and Count of Category 4:

```
[
  ["Product A",  0, 42, 83, 47],
  ["Product B",  0,  1,  4, 10],
  ["Product C",  0,  0,  2,  4],
  ["Product D",  6, 13, 57, 27]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
groups.group_by { |(p,_),_| p }.map do |product, prod_groups| 
  [product, *(1..4).map do |category| 
    (prod_groups.find {|(_, c), v| c == "Category #{category}" }||[0]).last
  end]
end
# => [["Product A", 0, 42, 83, 47], ["Product B", 0, 1, 4, 10], ["Product C", 0, 0, 2, 4], ["Product D", 6, 13, 57, 27]]
```

Another option for arbitrary category names:

```
CATEGORY_NAMES = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4"]

groups.group_by { |(p,_),_| p }.map do |product, prod_groups| 
  sub_groups = Hash[prod_groups.map { |(p, c), v| [c, v] }]
  sub_groups.default = 0
  [product, *CATEGORY_NAMES.map { |c| sub_groups[c] }]
end
# => [["Product A", 0, 42, 83, 47], ["Product B", 0, 1, 4, 10], ["Product C", 0, 0, 2, 4], ["Product D", 6, 13, 57, 27]]
```

Comment: Nice use of destructuring bind.